# Data binding in angular 2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have 2 input boxes in my HTML file.

```
<div class="row">
   <label>Input1</label>
   <input type="text" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="model.valueInput1">
</div>

<div class="row">
   <label>Input2</label>
   <input type="text" name="input2" [(ngModel)]="model.valueInput2">
</div>
```

And my model is:

```
model = {
  valueInput1:string = "",
  valueInput2:string = ""
}
```

Now I want, when I bind 'input1', the value should bind with 'input2' automatic. But if I change 'input2' value, it should not make changes in 'input1'.

How can I achieve this kind of binding in Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
   <label>Input1</label>
   <input type="text" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="model.valueInput1" (ngModelChange)="updateInput($event)">
</div>
..........
```

In the ts

```
updateInput(value: string): void {
   this.model.valueInput2 = value;
}
```

that's it

Comment: so if it works, please mark it as correct answer. thanks